# Change the value of an object to Long

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want the value of the object to be not a double type but a Long type.

```
client.db("customDB").collection("chart").insertMany( [{"chart": data.chart}]...


  "chart" : [ 
    {
        "x" : 1635017640000.0, ----->   1635017640000 (LONG NUMBER)
        "y" : [ 
            0.13715, 
            0.13715001, 
            0.13714999, 
            0.13715
        ]
    }
 
]
```

Thank you :)

Comment: [{"contract": data.contract, "name": data.name, "chart": data.chart.map(function(item) {

      item.x = Long.fromNumber(item.x);

      return item;

         })}],

Answer (score 0):

parseInt(1635017640000.0) would be the way to go :)

No need to import anything.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Remember to google the issue - in javascript any floating point number is called float and any number without comma is an int or rather "integer"

Comment: `parseInt` takes a string for the argument.

Comment: Yet it works - but yeah Math.floor is peobably a better solution

Comment: Works on one browser?  Or all of them? :)  Probably converts to a string, then parses. Hehe.

Comment: [{"contract": data.contract, "name": data.name, "chart": data.chart.map(function(item) {

      item.x = Long.fromNumber(item.x);

      return item;

         })}],

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.floor` to convert to an integer and strip the fraction.

The `Math.floor()` function returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor

```js
{
  x: Math.floor(123.456)
}
```

Results in

```js
{
  x: 123
}
```

Comment: [{"contract": data.contract, "name": data.name, "chart": data.chart.map(function(item) {

      item.x = Long.fromNumber(item.x);

      return item;

         })}],